# PHP - Save JSON with pre-fixed tag

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

Right now, I have this MySQL data set which saves to JSON file using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). It works fine.

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, explanation FROM questions ".
"WHERE quiz_id=?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
    $json = array();
    $result = $resultSet->fetch_all();
    echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Which will output to a file something like this:

```
[
    [
        "Water",
        "Theiving",
        "Deception",
        "The Underworld",
        "Poseidon is one of the twelve Olympian deities of the pantheon in Greek mythology."
    ],
    [
        "To complete a challenge",
        "To impress his wife",
        "As an act of revenge",
        "To defeat Hades",
        "As an act of revenge, for being tricked by Prometheus, Zeus hid fire from mankind. Out of pity, Prometheus stole it back"
    ],
    [
        "A friend",
        "His son",
        "An enemy",
        "His grandfather",
        "He was overthrown by his own son Zeus and imprisoned in Tartarus. He ate his children and took advantage of his wife."
    ]
]
```

My question is, how do I make it so can prefix it with titles like this?

```
[
    "answer_1": "A friend",
    "answer_2": "His son",
    "answer_3": "An enemy",
    "answer_4": "His grandfather",
    "explanation" : "He was overthrown by his own son Zeus and imprisoned in Tartarus. He ate his children and took advantage of his wife."
]
```

That way, it is more read-able and easier to understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change it to:

```
$result = $resultSet->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```